Wait for broadcast to complete before starting process in Flink
I have a BroadcastProcessFunction in flink with the process method implemented more or less as such:
    @Override
    public void processElement(String raw, ReadOnlyContext ctx, Collector<F> out) throws Exception {
        try {

            C data = ctx.getBroadcastState(this.stateDescriptor).get(null);
            if (data == null) {
                return;
            }
            F fm = this.parser.parse(raw);
            if (fm == null) {
                return;
            }
             
             /// business logic

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("process failed", e);
        }
    }

the problem is that the processing starts before the broadcast state is ready and some data is lost. I have tried to block the processing and relying on backpressure to pause processing until the state is ready as such:
 @Override
    public void processElement(String raw, ReadOnlyContext ctx, Collector<F> out) throws Exception {
        try {

            C data = getData(ctx);
            if (data == null) {
                return;
            }
            F fm = this.parser.parse(raw);
            if (fm == null) {
                return;
            }
            // ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("process failed", e);
        }
    }

    peivate C getData(ReadOnlyContext ctx) {
        int maxAttempts = 10000;
        C data;
        for (int attempt = 0; attempt < maxAttempts; attempt++) {
            try {
                data = ctx.getBroadcastState(SourceFunction.this.stateDescriptor).get(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                data = null;
            }
            if (data != null) {
                return data;
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1_000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

but this way the broadcast seems to get stuck, why is it and how do I solve the problem of data loss in the broadcast period?

Historically, I've had to deal with this numerous times and there's a few ways to handle it depending on your infrastructure and what "works best" in your case:

Bootstrapping Operators - For some very large states, I've found that it can be useful to run a batch-based "bootstrap" job prior to your main job that uses the State Processor API to construct a savepoint that your primary job is restored from. This will allow you to define the state that you want to store in your specific operators and start the job with all of the existing state while still allowing you to listen for changes that come in.
In-Job Bootstrapping - You could perform something similar depending on the size of your state where you could query (depending on where your broadcast state is sourced) when the job is started along with some type of flag to only perform this when necessary. Basically, you would issue a query prior to executing your job graph and use that to seed the state within your job.
Hybrid State - I believe that this was the problem that Hybrid Sources were designed to solve by allowing you to sequentially execute certain parts of your pipeline. I'd imagine in theory you could use this to load your existing state and then pivot over to a stream of incoming updates that are broadcast downstream. (Note: I haven't used Hybrid State extensively but it may be an option worth looking into).

